# Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables on EXPLAIN for a UPDATE statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, explain

I've the following UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.Day = t2.Day AND t1.Id = t2.Id)
SET  
t1.Price = t2.Price,
t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t2.Id = 1
AND t2.Day = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

When running a EXPLAIN statement I get the message back as

> Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

At the moment selecting a range of 21 records is returned in about 0.400 seconds on average.

I've already added a Index on the fields t2.Id and t2.Day.  Basically the requirement of this update statement is to take all records that exist in Table2 with the Id of 1 for each Day (or all Dates between DayStart and DayEnd, which I have access to).

Is there anyway on improving this in terms of performance, or should I not worry about the EXPLAIN result ?

Comment: What is the question? Is it to get rid of the "Impossible WHERE..." message or to improve your update query?

Comment: Place the ',' to separate updated column like  t1.Price = t2.Price , t1.Name = t2.Name.

Comment: @hacksteak25 I added to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: with this time `0.400 seconds on average.` the explain message would bothered me.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Which is why I asked for help improving it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.Day = t2.Day AND t1.Id = t2.Id)
WHERE t2.Id = 1
AND t2.Day = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2013-11-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

will return an empty result.

`Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` is not performance related. The `EXPLAIN` is just telling you that there is no dataset found with your given WHERE condition. So maybe there are no datasets in Table2 with Id = 1 OR Day = '2013-11-02'?

If you solved the `Impossible WHERE...` you can start optimizing your query with the EXPLAIN result (400ms seems to be very slow).